# Having trouble using cURL's PUT in PHP

Tags: php

I am having trouble doing cURL PUT in PHP for a REST API. It says 401 Unauthorized and I am quite new to php so I didn't know what to do please help me.

```
<?php
$url = "https://app.linkemperor.com/api/v2/vendors/blasts/6949235.json";
$data = '{"blasts": {"links" : "http://doblajemexicano.com.mx/sitio/index.php?title=Keyword_Elite_,_The_Ferrari_Of_Search_phrases_Study
http://fi.caravanwiki.com/index.php/Keyword_Elite_,_The_Ferrari_Of_Keywords_and_phrases_Research"}}';


            $content = json_encode($data);
            $oneMB = 1024 * 1024;
            $fh = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:$oneMB', 'r+');
            fwrite($fh, $content);
            rewind($fh);
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<api key>:x");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($content));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

            $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

            if ( $status != 201 ) {
                die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
            }


            curl_close($curl);

            $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you entered the right username and password?

Comment: Yes the api key given to me is correct I double check it in the website

Comment: Was `d5942dbe4b2cfb46dd9046d3bc0d0235043c0a84` your *real* API key?  If so, you may want to change it.  You shouldn't include stuff like that in your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that I'll edit it right away

Comment: I removed it from the question for you, but you may want to login to the website and have them generate a new one.

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);`.

Comment: I had tried that api key in my other PHP script and it seems working. It correctly get the stuff I'm asking. I'm just having trouble with this one.

Comment: I added curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); but it still says 401.

Comment: The available methods are GET, POST, DELETE according to http://www.linkemperor.com/api-methods

Comment: Yes for the customer side but I'm in the partner side so we have PUT method [http://www.linkemperor.com/partner-api-methods](http://www.linkemperor.com/partner-api-methods)

Comment: Try using the [`api_key` GET parameter](http://www.linkemperor.com/partner-api-authentication) instead.  `curl_init($url.'?api_key=<api_key>');` (and then remove the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` and `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` lines).

Comment: @RocketHazmat still says 401 unauthorize

Comment: @JC007: I don't know what to tell ya.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Its ok maybe I'll write to support team thanks for the help